# Flink cluster - Error when Submitting Job

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-flink, apache-zookeeper

I have a K8s cluster on EKS with 1 JM, 30 TMs, 3 Zookeepers and we are using the Flinkoperator: https://github.com/lyft/flinkk8soperator

We use zookeeper for High availability mode run.
We are unable to get the flink job i.e our application submitted.

The strange thing is this exact same configuration works in other regions but on this newly setup region we are just unable to submit the Flink Job.

The Flink UI also does not seem accessibile for the new region.

Some observations:

1. There are some errors in the zookeeper initially but it eventually runs fine and gives Processing... log for the rest.
2. Job manager is where error seems prominent but we are not sure why this problem is
3. Flink operator just tells us it could not submit the job.
4. TM logs don't have too much data.

Would anyone know how to proceed here? Or possibly have a hint as to what is going on? Could it be a resourcing issue as per: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg21146.html

But then we are using beefy nodes for the pods similar to our deployments to other regions.

Any insights or pointers here would be appreciated.

Here are the logs from the different pods: (Sorry if they are too long)

1. Flink operator:

> {"json":{"app_name":"my-app","ns":"flink-cluster","phase":"SubmittingJob"},"level":"info","msg":"Handle
> state skipped for application, lastSeenError UnknownMethod call failed
> with status FAILED and message '': Could not find deployments for
> service my-app","ts":"2021-09-28T15:35:54Z"}
> {"json":{"app_name":"my-app","ns":"flink-cluster","phase":"SubmittingJob"},"level":"info","msg":"Handle
> state skipped for application, lastSeenError UnknownMethod call failed
> with status FAILED and message '': Could not find deployments for
> service my-app","ts":"2021-09-28T15:36:24Z"}

2. Task manager (1 of them):

> 2021-09-28 16:13:02,940 ERROR
> org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] -
> Registration at ResourceManager failed due to an error
> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
> org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.FencingTokenException: Fencing
> token not set: Ignoring message
> RemoteFencedMessage(8bb0ba2f8de9e3fa13b269deba364c70,
> RemoteRpcInvocation(registerTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorRegistration,
> Time))) sent to
> akka.tcp://flink@100.117.59.33:35805/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0
> because the fencing token is null.    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:235)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1044)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:573)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:101)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:999)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:458)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
> [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]   at
> akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
> [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]   at
> akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
> [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]   at
> akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
> [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1] Caused by:
> org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.FencingTokenException: Fencing
> token not set: Ignoring message
> RemoteFencedMessage(8bb0ba2f8de9e3fa13b269deba364c70,
> RemoteRpcInvocation(registerTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorRegistration,
> Time))) sent to
> akka.tcp://flink@100.117.59.33:35805/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0
> because the fencing token is null.    at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:67)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:159)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  at
> akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
> ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]  ... 9 more 2021-09-28
> 16:13:02,947 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor
> [] - Pausing and re-attempting registration in 10000 ms 2021-09-28
> 16:13:03,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor
> [] - Terminating registration attempts towards ResourceManager
> akka.tcp://flink@100.117.59.33:35805/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0.
> 2021-09-28 16:13:03,378 INFO
> org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] -
> Connecting to ResourceManager
> akka.tcp://flink@100.117.59.33:35805/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0(8ebb566d5f310905d0421f7fe9a74498).
> 2021-09-28 16:13:03,383 INFO
> org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] -
> Resolved ResourceManager address, beginning registration 2021-09-28
> 16:13:03,390 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor
> [] - Successful registration at resource manager
> akka.tcp://flink@100.117.59.33:35805/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0 under
> registration id 78d410e0d100d4712171571f087b6476.

3. Job manager:

> ```
>  2021-09-28 16:13:30,063 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager []
> ```
>
> - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID 120.117.67.21:34443-d3dd7f (akka.tcp://flink@120.117.67.21:34443/user/rpc/taskmanager_0) at
>   ResourceManager
>   2021-09-30 15:36:33,455 WARN  akka.remote.Remoting                                         [] - Association to [akka.tcp://flink@120.117.78.156:33767] with
>   unknown UID is irrecoverably failed. Address cannot be quarantined
>   without knowing the UID, gating instead for 50 ms.
>   2021-09-30 15:42:25,636 ERROR akka.remote.Remoting                                         [] - Association to [akka.tcp://flink@120.117.79.241:40783] with UID
>   [-210531468] irrecoverably failed. Quarantining address.
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Remote system has been silent for too long. (more than 48.0 hours)
>   at akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor$$anonfun$idle$1.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:387)
>   ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]

4. Zookeeper: Please check link as it is too long.
   https://pastecode.io/s/as00i6pb